# Magento - Proceed to Checkout button location in theme

Tags: php, magento, file-location

I am looking to track down the file (and it's location) that generates the "Proceed to Checkout" button in the Magento cart.

Try adding a product to the cart, and then proceeding to the cart. The "Proceed to Checkout" button is on the right hand side of the cart.

I am using a hacked-about variation of the blank theme, if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 3 answers at exactly the same time ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code that produces the Proceed to Checkout link is in templates/checkout/onepage/link.phtml

By default the block for it is in checkout.xml;

```
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>
```

Comment: Chosen as best answer due to thoroughness, though all other answers are correct. Thanks all, it was driving me mad trying to find it.

Comment: Excellent - sanity preserved......for the moment. Magento's next hair tearing scenario is surely not far off!

Answer (score 3):

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Proceed to Checkout" button that leads to the onepage checkout, is generated with this template : `checkout/onepage/link.phtml`.

You should be able to know what buttons are added with which templates by looking at the `checkout_cart_index` handle of the `checkout.xml` layout file. The block named `checkout.cart.methods` contains all the buttons, and the two base checkout buttons should be added to it directly in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *System* -> *Configuration* -> *Developer* change a *Current Configuration Scope* to some of your websites or stores than go to *Debug* section - and change *Template Path Hints* setting to "Yes". Now, on frontend, you'll see an full path to your template file on a filesystem for every block that rendered, so now you can see where your template (that renders a link) exists.

Answer (score 1):

Open this path in your root directory

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml
```

find this code

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
```